# How to manage database layer in Java database application without any ORM (JPA/Hibernate)?

Tags: java, database, jakarta-ee, jdbc, orm

I am willing to learn ORM later. But now I want to use pure SQL codes to manage the Data layer of my Java Web application and don't want to any ORM like framework. What is the best way or practice of it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggest to try `Spring-JDBC`. It's very easy to start and user. See examples below.

#### Spring JDBC

From [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html):

> Here is a simple query for getting the number of rows in a relation:

Don't forget that `jdbcTemplate` should be injected.

```
int rowCount = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select count(*) from t_actor", Integer.class);
```

#### jOOQ

From [documentation](http://www.jooq.org):

Using SQL below:

```
SELECT * FROM BOOK
   WHERE BOOK.PUBLISHED_IN = 2011
ORDER BY BOOK.TITLE
```

The same in `java` using `jOOQ`:

```
create.selectFrom(BOOK)
      .where(BOOK.PUBLISHED_IN.eq(2011))
      .orderBy(BOOK.TITLE)
```

Both are very convenient. But regarding to usage of *pure* `SQL` - I recommend to start using `Spring JDBC`.

#### Disclaimer

If you are starting your path - highly suggest to start using just plain `JDBC` in order to be familiar what kind of boilerplate code is running under the hood of the frameworks.

---

## DAO & DTO

**DAO** (Data Access Object) is a class that usually has the **CRUD** (*create, read, update, delete*) operations - save, read, update, delete.

**DTO** (Data Transfer Object) is just an *object that holds* data. It is a JavaBean with instance variables and setter and getters. Usually it is the DTO that is passed to the save method of a DAO.

### Example

**Student.java**

```
public class Student {
   private String name;
   private int rollNo;

   Student(String name, int rollNo){
      this.name = name;
      this.rollNo = rollNo;
   }

   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }

   public int getRollNo() {
      return rollNo;
   }

   public void setRollNo(int rollNo) {
      this.rollNo = rollNo;
   }
}
```

**StudentDao.java**

```
public interface StudentDao {
   List<Student> getAllStudents();
   Student getStudent(int rollNo);
   void updateStudent(Student student);
   void deleteStudent(Student student);
}
```

**StudentDaoImpl.java**

```
public class StudentDaoImpl implements StudentDao {
    //list is working as a database
   private static final List<Student> students;

   public StudentDaoImpl() {
      students = new ArrayList<Student>();
      students.add(new Student("Student 0", 0));
      students.add(new Student("Student 1", 1));        
   }

   @Override
   public void deleteStudent(Student student) {
      students.remove(student.getRollNo());
      System.out.println("Student: Roll No " + student.getRollNo() + ", deleted from database");
   }

   @Override
   public List<Student> getAllStudents() {
      return students;
   }

   @Override
   public Student getStudent(int rollNo) {
      return students.get(rollNo);
   }

   @Override
   public void updateStudent(Student student) {
      Student foundStudent = students.get(student.getRollNo())
      foundStudent.setName(student.getName());
      System.out.println("Student: Roll No " + student.getRollNo() + ", updated in the database");
   }
}
```

**DaoPatternDemo.java**

```
public class DaoPatternDemo {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      StudentDao studentDao = new StudentDaoImpl();

      for (Student student : studentDao.getAllStudents()) {
         System.out.println("Student: [RollNo : " + student.getRollNo() + ", Name : " + student.getName() + " ]");
      }

      Student student = studentDao.getAllStudents().get(0);
      student.setName("Michael"); // here student is our DTO because we are
                                  // passing it into our DAO
      studentDao.updateStudent(student);

      studentDao.getStudent(0);
      System.out.println("Student: [RollNo : " + student.getRollNo() + ", Name : " + student.getName() + " ]");      
   }
}
```

To learn more - please visit also this [resource](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/data_access_object_pattern.htm).

Comment: yes I know how to use jdbc api. but I want to know how to use it effectively so that I have a clear seperation of data access and business logic operations. I heard something like DTO or DAO...Can you plz explain these with examples?

Comment: updated answer. Hope it'll help.